# How can I get PathSegment for the root @Path

Tags: jax-rs

With following resource class,

```java
@Path("/cities")
public class CitiesResource {

    public Response read(
        @PathParam("???") final PathSegment path) {

        // ...
    }
}
```

How can I get a `PathSegment` for the root `@Path("/cities")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get all the `PathSegment`s from [`UriInfo.getPathSegments()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html#getPathSegments--)

```
@GET
public String read(@Context UriInfo info) {
    List<PathSegment> segments = info.getPathSegments();
}
```